# Under what conditions can we manipulate operators algebraically?

Tags: operator-theory

Here's a derivation of a series expansion for $e$ that I saw [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpGpy9zLdkQ&t=96s):

$$\int_0^x e^y \textrm{d}y = e^y|_0^x = e^x-1$$

Define an operator $I=\int_0^x$ and we have

$$I e^x = e^x-1$$

$$[1-I]e^x=1$$

We not have a new operator $\frac{1}{1-I}$ such that

$$e^x=\frac{1}{1-I} [1] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty I^k[1]$$

$$ = 1 + \int_0^x 1 \textrm{d}x + \int_0^x \int_0^x 1 \textrm{d}x \textrm{d}x + ...$$

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Some manipulations of operators are intuitive to me, for example if $I$ and $J$ are both linear operators, then it seems reasonable that $aI+bJ$ would be reasonable notation for another linear operator with the obvious properties. However I don't see any reason to suppose that $\frac{1}{1-I}$ even exists, let alone that it can be evaluated as a series expansion.

Under what conditions can we treat operators using normal algebraic operations, and interpret the resulting expressions accordingly?

Comment: This falls under the umbrella of "operator calculus". An unsatisfying but useful answer would be "you can do so whenever it works", and by "it works" I mean, there's a second way to check that your results make sense.

Comment: On your second to last line, be careful about using $x$ as a limit and the variable of integration. Needs to be a dummy variable.

Comment: Notationally, I would write $\frac 1{1-I}$ as $(1-I)^{-1}$, which is the resolvent operator corresponding to $\lambda = 1$. Generally, if $\lambda\not \in\sigma(I)$ (i.e. the spectrum), you may define the bijection $(\lambda - I)^{-1}$, which is a bijection from $X\to D(I)$, where $X$ is the corresponding Banach space. Note that (a) the spectrum usually consists of more than just the point spectrum, and (b) you need to define an appropriate Banach space $X$ for this to be rigorous.

Comment: For example, in quantum mechanics it's extremely common to write $e^{a\frac{d}{dx}} = f(x+a)$ this has a derivation using taylor series and therefore is only true for "analytic functions" in a sense. Some of the other identites out there like the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula via $\frac{1}{1-e^{\frac{d}{dx}}}$ seem to work on a heck of a lot more than just analytic functions. So each such operator identity has a different set of conditions, specific to the identity, where it works

Comment: I would put no more faith in this derivation than i would put into the derivation that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k = -\frac 1{12}$. The best that can be said about it is that if $e^x$ is expressible as a power series, then this is what it should be. If we didn't already know by proper derivations that this power series really does converge to $e^x$, the weakness of the argument would garner our attention far more strongly.